# c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function error on Google Visualization Table API

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Hi I need a little help here. I was trying to create a table and I need my one column to be sortable which contains date and time from a database timestamp and I found some techniques to do so. But when I try it on my codes I always get "c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function(..)" error.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Here are my codes:
**PHP**

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    //Labels for the chart, these represent the column titles
     array('id' => '', 'label' => 'acct_name', 'type' => 'string'),
     array('id' => '', 'label' => 'number_of_hours', 'type' => 'number'),
     array('id' => '', 'label' => 'last_login', 'type' => 'date')

    ); 

$rows = array();
foreach($exec as $row){
    $temp = array();

//Values
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['acct_name']);
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['number_of_hours']);
$temp[] = array('v' =>  Date($row['last_login']));
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows; 

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

**JavaScript**

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
  var options = {

    };


var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'medium'});
dateFormatter.format(data, 2);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
table.draw(data, options);
}
```

I already tried using the following datetime format but no use:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => Date("Y-m-d h:i" , strtotime($row['last_login'])));

$temp[] = array('v' =>  new DateTime($row['last_login']));

$temp[] = array('v' =>  new DateTime(date("Y-m-d h:i" , strtotime($row['last_login']))));
```

Anything else?. thanks in advance

Comment: formatting a php date column, _for google-vis_, can be a chore -- [here is a detailed example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39756555/5090771) -- [here is another, less complicated example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35157059/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat It works. Thanks for the answer